# while executing via localhost I got these error. How to resolve it?

Tags: php, magento

I want to run magento site using localhost. I downloaded it through site and tried to run it using localhost but it gives me all these error.

I exactly don't know the idea what exactly is going on, in files what changes are required to run the code. If this error is related to database then from where I will get the username, password & localhost name.

Can anyone please help me sort this problem?

[image]

Comment: u'll get the db details in app/etc/local.xml file

Comment: it is seems to be error of db connection. please check once

Comment: Your user account cannot access the database using the provided credentials. Check them or try logging in using a tool such as phpmyadmin.

Comment: i got it & changed db details, then i recorrect the localhost path in addressbar to 'c\wamp......\dap' only but now  it shows site but instead of showing site with localhost path, shows the actual site with it's main domain name. i don't think this is correct. Guys do you any idea @ Manashvi birla &  @Deep Kakkar

Comment: Please don't paste images when copying/pasting text is possible as it (a) makes it harder for people to answer, and (b) makes the page load more slowly, reducing the likelihood that you will get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the file in app/etc/local.xml
- Check/Edit the DB credentials
- For URL, open table `core_config_data`
- change the value of `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` with your required value e.g. example.com/

**Note that if you are working on localhost then you have to create [Virtual Host](http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/) with site name.**

Comment: If you wants to open site with above URL address  then update value with http://localhost/projects/dap/ i.e. use http:// before localhost

Comment: before commenting i did the same thing but no use then i removed http:// .but still the problem isn't solved. you mentioned about virtual host. do you have any link from where i should create host name.

Comment: click on the Virtual host text in the answer.

Comment: if you are getting site on that URL then what are you looking for dear?

Comment: see yesterday i told you  i want to make some changes into that site. if i make changes into hosted site dashboard then it reflected on site too. so as am newbie, first i want to make change fom localhost then on hosted site. but in my case instead of showing site with its localhost path, it directly display the main hosted site link.

Comment: Is on open the localhost path site is redirecting to live path ? Please come on chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79528/discussion-between-deep-kakkar-and-sandy-sharma).

Comment: Hey sandy, please approve my answer